# how to get file name of the upload file using form type is ModelForm directly from models.Models

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

I've been trying to find a solution for a while now, but I still haven't found anything that could help me,
so if one of you has any idea how to solve my problem, I would be really thankful. I am new to Django (total beginner), I provided my code below.

#### models.py

```py
    class Video(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      video = models.FileField(upload_to="video/%y/%m")
      upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
      def str(self):
        return self.title +'@' +str(self.upload)
```

#### form.py

```py
    class VideoForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta: 
        model = Video 
        fields = ['video']
```

#### views.py

```py
    def upload(request): 
      vidform = VideoForm() 
      if request.method == 'POST': 
        vidform = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if vidform.is_valid(): 
            name = request.FILES['file'].name 
            print(name)
            Video().save
        else:
          vidform = VideoForm()
        return render (request, 'base/home.html')
      context = {'vidform':vidform,}
      return render (request, 'base/upload.html',context)
```

When I try to upload a file Django returns...

```bash
    Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
    Exception Value:'file'
```

how can I get the uploaded file name and assign to the title
the video title is needed to store on the database

Comment: hello @Nattan_45 

when you want file name after saving or before saving form ??

Comment: I just want to see the video name (title) of the uploaded file inside of my database model along with the upload-time (models.DateTimeField) and the video (models.FileField) itself @Mahammadhusain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I tried to solve your problem.

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      video = models.FileField(upload_to="video/%y/%m")
      upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      def str(self):
         return self.title +'@' +str(self.upload)
```

#### form.py

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import Video

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta: 
      model = Video 
      fields = ['video']
```

#### HTML Code

```
{% block body %}
  <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

#### views.py

```
def InsertData(request):
    form = VideoForm() 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            name = form.cleaned_data['video'] 
            print(name)
            form.save()
    context= {'form':form}
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

#### Output in terminal (I saved a file whose name has Animation.gif)

[image]

#### In Admin Panel

[image]